# Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete

I have implemented google places api in my website for showing the address list and it is throwing error mentioned below.

Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error. Your site URL to be authorized: mysiteurl.com

Because of this error the text box I implemented google places is disabled and unable to proceed.

```
<input id="address" required="" type="text" gm-places-autocomplete="gm-places-autocomplete" ng-model="autocomplete" placeholder="Oops! Something went wrong." value="" ng-focus="expandAddress=true" ng-init="expandAddress=false" class="address-trigger form-control ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required gm-err-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" disabled="" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/icon_error.png&quot;);">
```

---

Basically, I want a fallback, if the google places fail to load properly. User still should be able to write address and proceed.

Please help me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you show the Angular code you have used. Plus, you could go to the API console -> credentials and choose the API in question and set the  Key restriction to None - This will remove any restrictions to the key.

Answer (score -1):

http://postcodes.io/ is one alternative if you are only interested in a UK-based fallback.

You don't say whether the data had particular constraints.